# Where did iTextSharp's Rtf support go

Tags: c#, .net, itext

with version 5, iText has been split into two branches - iText PDF & iText RTF.

iTextSharp, which I use, seem to be iText PDF now. Is there a iText RTF port for .NET yet? I would think that iTextSharp homepage would mention this, but there is nearly no useful information, only file download, I don't even find a way to contact iTextSharp supporters or any forum for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer of the RTF code in iText has Gone Away (I don't know the reason).  That RTF code was split into its own source forge project and abandoned/ignored/whatever-you-want-to-call-it.

iText and iTextSharp are strictly HTML/PDF these days... mostly PDF.